# Unity 5 - How to change Input Field 'Content Type' at runtime to toggle between asterisks and letters?

Tags: unity, input

I have a password box set up in my project with the content type set to 'Password', so it shows asterisks when the user types in the box. However I would like a toggle switch so the user can click to show the password characters if they like, so effectively toggling between 'Password' and 'Standard' - is this possible? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Unity 5.3.5 - PC Standalone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I assume you have a simple scene set up with a [Toggle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle.html) and an [InputField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html) like this:

[image]

Add a new Empty to your scene and name it `UIController`. Select your newly created object, head over to the Inspector and hit the `Add Component` button to create and attach a new custom component. Name the script `UIController` and paste the following code (I'm assuming C#):

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIController : MonoBehaviour {

    public UnityEngine.UI.InputField passwordInput = null;

    public void ToggleInputType() {
        if (this.passwordInput != null) {
            if (this.passwordInput.contentType == InputField.ContentType.Password) {
                this.passwordInput.contentType = InputField.ContentType.Standard;
            } else {
                this.passwordInput.contentType = InputField.ContentType.Password;
            }

            this.passwordInput.ForceLabelUpdate ();
        }
    }
}
```

The script's public method is basically the answer to your question. Probably one thing to mention is the call to `forceLabelUpdate` after switching the [InputField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html)'s contentType, otherwise the display-mode doesn't update immediately.

Just to be complete:

1. Of course you have to wire the reference to your specific [InputField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html). To do this, select your UIController in the outline to have the UIController's properties visible in the Inspector. Then drag&drop the [InputField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html) to link it to the 'Password Field' member:

[image]

2. And finally, build the bridge from the [Toggle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle.html) to the UIController's `ToggleInputType()` method. Select the [Toggle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle.html) and scroll all the way down to the bottom:

[image]

From this section (outlined in blue) you can specify any object in your scene to be informed when the user interacts with the [Toggle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle.html). Here you want to choose the UIController as the object (green) and its `ToggleInputType` method (red) to be invoked.

Wow. This got longer than expected but I hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to write that up, it's much appreciated. I shall give it a go and let you know how I get on.

Comment: i was missing `ForceLabelUpdate()`. thank you!